# Convert any document's pages to images

Tags: iphone, ios, document

Converting PDF pages to images can be achieved by rendering each pdf page in a bitmap context (CGContextDrawPDFPage).

Can we do the same with other document types (iWork, MS Office etc).

We can just show the preview for all these documents using UIDocumentInteractionController or QuickLook framework. But neither can be customized or does not give me access to individual pages.

Same is the case with UIDocument. It can give me entire contents as NSData or NSFileWrapper but i'm not sure how do i render it page by page (say in a bitmap context).

Is there any way to convert other document pages to images?

UPDATE:

No progress on this so far. UIWebView, UIDocumentInterationController and QLPreview are the only things which i could find for even viewing the office/iWork documents let alone convert them to images.

Does anyone have any experience/idea about customizing document interaction controller or quick look preview controller to render documents page by page?

Comment: I also want to implement this but not finding the solution other then uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

I think you can open the document in UIWebview and take screen shot of the view.

Comment: how do i scroll the web view to each page for taking snapshot? plus web view adds a fancy background which shows up either above and below or on the sides (depending on the aspect ratio of your document wrt the webview frame) i do not want that in my page image. i want only the page..

Comment: Ya. You have those difficulties. :( You will have to find the frames somehow to get snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we do the same with other document types (iWork, MS Office etc).

You can if you know how to render the content for the document types in question. [QA1630](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html) contains some hints, including a list of document types that you can display in UIWebView, although it's not clear that it's easy to break such documents into pages this way.

> Same is the case with UIDocument. It can give me entire contents as
>   NSData or NSFileWrapper but i'm not sure how do i render it page by
>   page (say in a bitmap context).

UIDocument is an abstract class -- it doesn't know anything about specific document types. You have to subclass UIDocument to provide the details of how data is formatted. So you'll be able to display your own documents types, but you can't display documents from other applications unless you know how those documents store their data.

Comment: @celeb: my issue is not rendering. the link you've mentioned only talks about rendering these file formats using web view. i can already do it much better with a quick look preview (which, i suspect, uses a web view too)